# Strange Behavior with String Arrays in C

Tags: c

I've been having some difficulties with strings in C - especially when it comes to File I/O. I've looked through some previous threads to see how to make string arrays in C, and I have come up with this.

```
void CreateBiomes()
{
    const int STRING_LENGTH = 32;
    const int BIOME_COUNT = 63;
    const char *biomes[BIOME_COUNT][STRING_LENGTH+1] = {"beaches", "birch_forest", "birch_forest_hills", "cold_beach", "deep_ocean", "desert", "desert_hills", "extreme_hills", "extreme_hills_with_trees", "forest", "forest_hills", "frozen_ocean", "frozen_river", "hell", "ice_flats", "ice_mountains", "jungle", "jungle_edge", "jungle_hills", "mesa", "mesa_clear_rock", "mesa_rock", "mushroom_island", "mushroom_island_shore", "mutated_birch_forest", "mutated_birch_forest_hills", "mutated_desert", "mutated_extreme_hills", "mutated_extreme_hills_with_trees", "mutated_forest", "mutated_ice_flats", "mutated_jungle", "mutated_jungle_edge", "mutated_mesa", "mutated_mesa_clear_rock", "mutated_mesa_rock", "mutated_plains", "mutated_redwood_taiga", "mutated_redwood_taiga_hills", "mutated_roofed_forest", "mutated_savanna", "mutated_savanna_rock", "mutated_swampland", "mutated_taiga", "mutated_taiga_cold", "ocean", "plains", "redwood_taiga", "redwood_taiga_hills", "river", "roofed_forest", "savanna", "savanna_rock", "sky", "smaller_extreme_hills", "stone_beach", "swampland", "taiga", "taiga_cold", "taiga_cold_hills", "taiga_hills", "void"};

    for(int i = 0; i <= BIOME_COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *biomes[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

The issue is - this code only works for "beaches" and "mutated_mesa" before the program crashes. Everything compiles great, it just won't process any of the other strings I've listed in my array, instead, it prints a (null). Why is this?

Comment: You've defined an array of array **of pointers** - that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Instead of `const char *biomes[BIOME_COUNT][STRING_LENGTH+1]` use `const char *biomes[BIOME_COUNT]`

Comment: And after you fix that, you'd probably want to fix the loop so as to not read outside the array boundary.

Comment: Does this compile without warnings? If not you might want to fix the code until no more wanrings are issued.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that's not what I wanted at all. Once I removed the * it suddenly worked. But why didn't the pointers work anyway?

Comment: @XaveJ - Because arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. Keep on programming and learning.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Agreed.  But in this particular case, even if pointers *were* arrays, it still wouldn't have been the right thing (semantically speaking, the OP needs only two dimensions).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - True, but I believe the OP's confusion may have stemmed from this misconception that is still stubbornly taught in many places.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= BIOME_COUNT; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < BIOME_COUNT; i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the declaration

```
const char *biomes[BIOME_COUNT][STRING_LENGTH+1]
```

as follows.

```
const char biomes[BIOME_COUNT][STRING_LENGTH+1]
```

Comment: not able to fix that with the solution suggested here. I keep getting excess elements in array initializer and then segfualt. why is that?

Comment: Alternative: `char const* biomes[] = { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Your array was a 2-D array of pointers, and, you indexed one too many in the `printf` loop.

I have changed this to a 1-D array of pointers, and also removed the hard coded sizes. Instead I replaced the last string `"void"` with a `NULL` pointer, and used that to control the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void CreateBiomes(void)
{
    const char *biomes[] = {"beaches", "birch_forest", "birch_forest_hills", "cold_beach", "deep_ocean", "desert", "desert_hills", "extreme_hills", "extreme_hills_with_trees", "forest", "forest_hills", "frozen_ocean", "frozen_river", "hell", "ice_flats", "ice_mountains", "jungle", "jungle_edge", "jungle_hills", "mesa", "mesa_clear_rock", "mesa_rock", "mushroom_island", "mushroom_island_shore", "mutated_birch_forest", "mutated_birch_forest_hills", "mutated_desert", "mutated_extreme_hills", "mutated_extreme_hills_with_trees", "mutated_forest", "mutated_ice_flats", "mutated_jungle", "mutated_jungle_edge", "mutated_mesa", "mutated_mesa_clear_rock", "mutated_mesa_rock", "mutated_plains", "mutated_redwood_taiga", "mutated_redwood_taiga_hills", "mutated_roofed_forest", "mutated_savanna", "mutated_savanna_rock", "mutated_swampland", "mutated_taiga", "mutated_taiga_cold", "ocean", "plains", "redwood_taiga", "redwood_taiga_hills", "river", "roofed_forest", "savanna", "savanna_rock", "sky", "smaller_extreme_hills", "stone_beach", "swampland", "taiga", "taiga_cold", "taiga_cold_hills", "taiga_hills",
                             NULL };

    for(int i = 0; biomes[i] != NULL; i++) {        // changed loop control
        printf("%s\n", biomes[i]);                  // changed argument passed
    }
}

int main(void){
    CreateBiomes();
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this function won't do much good, because `biomes`, a local variable, will not be accessible after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, your code should work.

```
void CreateBiomes()
{

   int BIOME_COUNT = 63;
   char *biomes[]= {"beaches", "birch_forest", "birch_forest_hills", "cold_beach", "deep_ocean", "desert", "desert_hills", "extreme_hills", "extreme_hills_with_trees", "forest", "forest_hills", "frozen_ocean", "frozen_river", "hell", "ice_flats", "ice_mountains", "jungle", "jungle_edge", "jungle_hills", "mesa", "mesa_clear_rock", "mesa_rock", "mushroom_island", "mushroom_island_shore", "mutated_birch_forest", "mutated_birch_forest_hills", "mutated_desert", "mutated_extreme_hills", "mutated_extreme_hills_with_trees", "mutated_forest", "mutated_ice_flats", "mutated_jungle", "mutated_jungle_edge", "mutated_mesa", "mutated_mesa_clear_rock", "mutated_mesa_rock", "mutated_plains", "mutated_redwood_taiga", "mutated_redwood_taiga_hills", "mutated_roofed_forest", "mutated_savanna", "mutated_savanna_rock", "mutated_swampland", "mutated_taiga", "mutated_taiga_cold", "ocean", "plains", "redwood_taiga", "redwood_taiga_hills", "river", "roofed_forest", "savanna", "savanna_rock", "sky", "smaller_extreme_hills", "stone_beach", "swampland", "taiga", "taiga_cold", "taiga_cold_hills", "taiga_hills", "void"};
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < BIOME_COUNT-1; i++)
   {
    printf("%s\n", biomes[i]);
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: `int count = sizeof(biomes)/sizeof(*biomes);` type this code on compiler you will get size of length this string. As every array start with 0 I have to substract 1;

Comment: If there are `BIOME_COUNT` elements in the array you do not need to subtract 1, the loop will work properly. In addition you must remove the `*` before `biomes[i]` in the call to `printf`.

Comment: It was correct before your edit, and now wrong. My comment was about readability, suggest `i < BIOME_COUNT` is more easily understood by humans than `i <= BIOME_COUNT - 1` even if the compiler does not mind.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for comment, the code is working well in my compiler.